# Convert List<Map<String, Object>> to String[][]

Tags: java, list, collections

I have a `List<Map<String, Object>> data`.

```
public List<Map<String, Object>> selectAll(String tableName) throws SQLException{
    MapListHandler mapListHandler = new MapListHandler();
    QueryRunner queryRunner = new QueryRunner();
    List<Map<String, Object>> list = queryRunner.query(DBConnection.getConnection(), SELECT + tableName, mapListHandler);
    System.out.println(list);
    return list;
}
```

Then I get this

```
List<Map<String, Object>> data = databaseMetadata.selectAll(buttonElements.getTables_in_migrate_schema());
```

And I need to add it to JTable as rowData so it has to be `String[][]`.

I tried to make something like this.

```
JTable jTable = new JTable((Object[][]) data.toArray(), fields.toArray());
```

Can someone please say me how to convert? Thanks in advance!

Comment: List<Map> is 3D. String[][] is 2D. Can you show us what have you tried(code)?

Comment: What part of `data` do you want to see in e.g. column 5 of row 2? It's not at all obvious how you want that structure mapped to a JTable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already have the field's name, so just collect every map's value of list and collect as 2D Object array. You can use Stream API this way

```
Object[][] objList = data.stream().map(m -> m.values().toArray()).toArray(Object[][]::new);
```